# Validate CSS - Background Repeat Issue

Tags: html, css, validation

I want to validate my css, and I have a  problem with my background-repeat line. How should I write that in order for it to be validated.

```
#contentBackground
{
position: relative;
width: 1280px;
top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(../images/contentBG.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
}
```

This is my given error:

Value Error : background-repeat Too many values or values are not recognized : repeat-x repeat-y repeat-x repeat-y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe valid inputs are:

- repeat-x
- repeat-y
- repeat (which is both x and y)
- no-repeat

In your situation "repeat" would seem correct.

Comment: @Ryan - in that case, please click on the tick icon to accept the answer  :)